# What is the fundamental difference between the Ising and Potts models?

Tags: terminology, definition, hamiltonian, ising-model, spin-models

What I understand is that the only difference between the Ising and Potts models is that Ising has two types of spins, and Potts has *n* types of spins.

However, I am wondering if the Hamiltonian (energy formula) is the same or different.

Are the Hamiltonianas the same or different?

What other differences do they have?

Comment: Duplicate of [What is the fundamental difference between the Ising and Potts models?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9675/) on the Matter Modeling SE.

Comment: In the $q$-state Potts model, the spins can take $q$ possible values. The $2$-state Potts model coincides with the Ising model. The number of spin states $q$ has major consequences. Of course, it changes the quantitative behavior of the model, but it also leads to different *qualitative* properties: for instance, the (temperature-driven) phase transition in the Ising model (that is, when $q=2$) is of second order, while it becomes of first order when $q\geq q_c$, where $q_c=3$ in dimensions $d\geq 3$ and $q_c=3$ or $5$ in dimension $2$ (depending on the interaction range).